# Identify if column is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS OR YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am processing a `pandas` dataset and sometimes the date column will be in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. However, other times it is `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS` (day first instead of the month)

What is the best way to identify these circumstances and convert the records in the column to all be in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: A `datetime64` is a binary value, it has no format. Make sure you load dates as dates, not as text, from the start. Almost all databases have proper date types. Excel dates are binary values as well. When loading CSV files make sure you specify the date format in `read_csv`. There's simply no way to tell whether `04-07` is May 7 or July 4 afterwards

Comment: If you are stuck with a file and strings, then the only advice I can give is to investigate all values in a column to see if some would be impossible for a given format.  Like if one of the values exceeds 12, then you know that must be a day.  If you can assume the format is consistent throughout the column then that is a way to try.

Comment: `YYYY-DD-MM` is an insane format (since it's so close to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). How did that happen? More likely the problem is with how you're *loading* the data. How are you loading it exactly? Please provide a [mre]. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: In general, you can't. Something like `2022-04-13` is clearly `YYYY-MM-DD`, because there is no month 13. But you'll need more information to determine if `2022-04-12` is April 12 or December 4.